# Pipelight not Installing

Tags: pipelight

I really want to watch Netflix on Ubuntu, but I can't because Netflix has no support for it. i googled how to watch Netflix on Ubuntu, and it said something about installing pipelight. I tried and followed all the instructions, but it just wouldnt install. Every time i type in the install command, this happens:

```
waylon@waylon-Lenovo-G770:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:pipelight/stable'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

One time i tried it, it showed this:

```
waylon@waylon-Lenovo-G770:~$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:pipelight/stable

More info: https://launchpad.net/~pipelight/+archive/stable
Press [ENTER] to continue or ctrl-c to cancel adding it

Error reading https://launchpad.net/api/1.0/~pipelight/+archive/stable: Service Temporarily Unavailable
```

But that has only happened once, and it still ended in failure. I tried many solutions and fixes, but those failed too. Help!!

I use Ubuntu 14.04

Thanks,

Waylon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Launchpad was offline temporarily. I just checked and it was back online.

Try again to add the ppa.